# How to run/use Docker on a MacOS VM having a Windows host machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose, windows-10, virtual-machine, macos-catalina

I have installed Macos Catalina 10.15 on a VM (via VirtualBox version-6). My host machine has Windows-10 installed on it. I am new to Macos and faced a lot of problems while installing macos on a VM.

Now that I have installed Macos, I came to know that I have to install third party plugins such as home-brew etc in order to install some prerequisites for setting up an environment which requires Docker.

I am unable to install Docker in a VM. I have researched on it but unable to find any solution to it. I have found out one article/link which kind of gives me an hint but not a completely guided solution. The link to it is: [Under the Hood: Demystifying Docker For Mac CE Edition](http://collabnix.com/how-docker-for-mac-works-under-the-hood/). All I need is to use Docker on a VM (Macos based) having a Windows-10 as its host OS.

Comment: why not ubuntu in VM then use docker in it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55091359/can-i-install-docker-inside-a-mac-virtualbox-vm

Comment: @Adiii this setup might be handy for developing complicated docker run commands. Using docker within a linux vm is an altogether different beast.

Comment: Since Docker for Mac internally launches a Linux VM, I wouldn't be surprised if running it inside an OSX VM doesn't work well.  I agree that it'd be easier to either use a Linux VM directly; this is what Docker Machine/Docker Toolbox do.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to build docker from its sources. The easiest way to install docker is to use the official build: https://download.docker.com/mac/stable/Docker.dmg

Note that it might not even be possible yet to run docker on a virtual mac...